# How to insert/create a record in custom object using custom controller

Tags: custom-controller

While saving the vf page I am getting this error:Invalid character in identifier: getUsers__c.How to resolve this?

VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="createUsers">
  <apex:sectionHeader title="Registration Form" />
      <apex:form >
          <apex:pageBlock >
              <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" showHeader="true" title="Personal Details">
                  <apex:inputField value="{!Users__c.Name}"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!Users__c.Contact_No__c}"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!Users__c.Email__c}"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!Users__c.URL__c}"/>

              </apex:pageBlockSection>
              <apex:pageblockButtons >
                  <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!saveDetails}"/>
              </apex:pageblockButtons>
          </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class createUsers {

    public Users__c user{get;set;}
    //public String userInfo{get;set;}
    public createUsers()
    {
        user = new Users__c();
    }
    public PageReference saveDetails() {
        insert user;
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the controller you have it should be the variable name `{!user.` not `{!Users__c.` in the page. When you use a standard controller the variable defaults to the type name but here you have picked the variable name. So:

```
              <apex:inputField value="{!user.Name}"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!user.Contact_No__c}"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!user.Email__c}"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!user.URL__c}"/>
```

(I'm somewhat guessing that the page is trying to generate a getter call for the variable name and for your code when the getter name is created from `Users__c` it is invalid.)

Note that for what you have so far you could just use a [standard controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_std_actions.htm). If you want to add more logic than the standard controller supports, you can also then add in a [controller extension](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/projects/salesforce_developer_workshop/steps/creating_controller_extension).